# Azure Search - Cost study of MergeOrUpload operation?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've written two different functions to populate the same document but different attributes. One of the function updates A1,A2,A3 attributes of document X and other function updates A4,A5 attributes of same document X given the document id. They are using MergeOrUpload operation to update the document.

I'm trying to evaluate the cost of `MergeOrUpload` operation. How it works at the backend and does it read the entire document and then merge the new attribute values and push back the document to the index or what? How much cost-effective it is?

Comment: Cognitive search doesn't change data. It only indexes it. It's hard to understand what your question is.

Comment: Ok, so basically im trying to evaluate the cost of `MergeOrUpload` operation. How it works? Like in sql, does it read the entire data before making and pushing the change or what? I have edited the question for more clarity. Thanks for your time

Comment: _on what platform_? SQL? CosmosDB? MS Access?

Comment: the above question is for azure-cognitive-search which uses CosmosDB at backend to index the data

Comment: Where does `MergeOrUpload` come into it? Does Cognitive search perform this when building the index?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents

Comment: I imagine the `merge` operation would have to read the whole document in order to work out how to merge it. I recall that CosmosDB's cost is based on operations so too many indexes (CosmosDB indexes, not cognitive search) is actually more expensive than fewer indexes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/optimize-cost-throughput#optimize-by-changing-indexing-policy By cost I guess you actually mean $, not optimiser cost. I think your question is clearer now, but I don't think I can assist any further

Comment: I mean optimiser cost, how much optimistic is this approach?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to include all attributes in a single call, rather than first creating the document with A1, A2 and A3, and then sending a mergeOrUpdate call to add A4, A5 and A6. In the backend, all index files are "read-only" to facilitate the distributed and concurrent nature of the service, so when you update a document, we actually need to do a copy of the original document which includes the newly updated attributes.

Your best bet to get accurate cost would be to do your own testing using your own data and usage pattern, however, its likely that you will discover creating the document with all the attributes is the most efficient approach.